# text align to bottom

Tags: kineticjs

I would like to know if it is possible to allign text to bottom.  If I use function setY(), it will only move text into exact position, but if text is too long, it will appear out of canvas. What suggestions do you have?

Thanks

Comment: if you're using html5 can't you just use <script>
  context.textBaseline = 'bottom';
</script>?

Comment: yes, but what height and y coordination should be? because if I only type textBaseline: 'bottom' it does not work

Answer (score -1):

Let's say your Kinetic Stage object is called `stage` and your Kinetic Text object is called `text`:

```
// wrap lines to the full width if you want
text.setWidth(stage.getWidth());

// move text to the bottom
text.setY(stage.getHeight() - text.getHeight());
```

Basically, this takes your text and shoves it to the bottom, where it'd "overflow", and so we bring it up. We could have also accomplished this with a y-offset:

```
// move text to the bottom
text.setY(stage.getHeight());

// offset it up
text.setOffset({ y: text.getHeight() });
```

Setting the width will wrap your text in case it's too wide to fit in the stage otherwise.